# Cannot translate this C code to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Basically I need to translate this C code (http://pastebin.com/7EupfQ5n) to MIPS assembly. I took a crack at this, but I am having troubles.

What I have so far is this (http://pastebin.com/LpS6Mqr1). But when I run the code in a simulator, it runs in an infinite loop despite what I put into the array, and I cannot find where it is doing that. I would assume that it is referencing the array in an incorrect way in the while and if statements, but I'm not sure how or why.

If anyone can help, that would be very appreciated.

Also, is there a way to have a C to MIPS compiler (translator?) for Mac OSX? I have GCC installed but the -mips flag generates an error for me. Thanks!

Comment: I used "gcc -march=mips32". This is the error: "error: bad value (mip32) for -march= switch" (the gcc website says I can do this: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html)

Comment: I assume the version of GCC you're using was compiled for your native arch and not MIPS. You'll need to get a MIPS cross compiler version of GCC.

Comment: And where would I find that for Mac OS X?

Comment: I'm not sure; I've never done it. I think usually people just recompile GCC with different configure options set to get a cross compiling GCC.

Comment: macports has several mips cross-compilers: http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=mips

Comment: How would I run these?

Answer (score 0):

Next time please use a debugger or simulator to step through your code.
There were a few obvious errors that you could have noticed yourself.

1. All your `move` (pseudo-)instructions are reversed. Should be `move destination, source`.
2. You should initialize `$s0` with zero at the start, to be safe.
3. `bge $s3, $t4, sumBetween1If3` (line 87) is using the wrong registers (copy-paste error?). It should be `bge $s4, $s6, sumBetween1If3`
4. You should delete line 97, as that's useless in its current form,
   and outright harmful if you swap the operands (it would destroy your sum
   in `$s5`).
5. No idea what you wanted to do with lines 98-100, since you don't use
   `$ra` or the stack elsewhere. So those lines are messing up both and cause your endless loop. Simply delete those 3 lines.

Funnily enough, your array accesses are all right. There are many possibilities for improvement, though, most notably there is no need to load the array item twice. I assume you intend to remove all the superfluous jumps that just go the next instruction anyway.

Comment: 1) one-of the bad of assembly ATT.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check is to compare your assembly code with the output generated by a compiler.

You do not need gcc to do this (and go through all the tedious steps required to create a cross-platform compiler) if you already have clang installed on your machine. Unfortunately, however, the version of clang that's installed on Mac doesn't support mips, so you'll have to either get clang directly from llvm's website, or do it on a linux machine. Once you get clang, simply run

`clang -S -target mips -o mips.asm ./your_file.c`

and compare your assembly code with the `mips.asm` file.

I've included output of the command [here](http://pastebin.com/LjRB5mZg).